# Selecting first 250 data

Tags: matlab

I am new with matlab,
I need to select first 250 data from an imported xls file.
I could not do it.How can i do it. You can see my code below

```
x=xlsread('parca3d.xlsx', 'A:A');
y=xlsread('parca3d.xlsx', 'B:B');
z=xlsread('parca3d.xlsx', 'C:C');
xyz=[x y z];
v=xyz(:,[1:250])    % this line is not correct
```

Comment: You need to tell us the shapes of your variables. Type `whos` at the command. I'm assuming that y y and z are columns. That makes xyz some number of rows and 3 columns. If you're looking for the first 250 rows, `v = xyz(1:250,:);` Matlab references things by <row,col>

Comment: v = xyz(1:250,:) command works thank you for your help...

Comment: Answer your own question then. Someone may look for the same thing in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

```
x=xlsread('parca3d.xlsx', 'A:A');
y=xlsread('parca3d.xlsx', 'B:B');
z=xlsread('parca3d.xlsx', 'C:C');
xyz=[x y z];
v = xyz(1:250,:) % this line works well
```